# JSON парсинг android

Tags: java, android, json, парсер

Имеется такой `JSON`:

```
[
    {
        "id":1080505,
        "name":"Tove Lo",
        "genres":[
            "pop",
            "dance",
            "electronics"
        ],
        "tracks":81,
        "albums":22,
        "link":somelink,
        "description":description,
        "cover":{
            "small":somestring,
            "big":somestring1
        }
    },
    {
    ...
    }
]
```

- Каким образом мне его спарсить?
- Как я могу получить JSONArray, если нет имени JSONArray? Т.е. после "[" сразу идут элементы JSON.
- Каким образом его можно обработать? В последствии данные с JSON нужно забить в ListView.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    try {
        JSONArray rootJSON = new JSONArray(new JSONTokener(YourJson));
        for (int i = 0; i < rootJSON.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject o = rootJSON.getJSONObject(i);
            Log.d("TAG", o.getString("name"));
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Скажите пожалуйста, а если я к json в том формате, какой я кинул в самом начале, при его обработке StringBuilder'ом добавлю {"Artists":, т.е. дам имя JSON массиву. Это будет считаться слишком костылем?

Answer (score 4):

Вариант с использованием библиотеки [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson)

1. Создаем объекты-модели:

   ```
   public class Cover {

       @SerializedName("small")
       public String small;
       @SerializedName("big")
       public String big;
   }

   public class Example {

       @SerializedName("id")
       public int id;
       @SerializedName("name")
       public String name;
       @SerializedName("genres")
       public List<String> genres = new ArrayList<String>();
       @SerializedName("tracks")
       public int tracks;
       @SerializedName("albums")
       public int albums;
       @SerializedName("link")
       public String link;
       @SerializedName("description")
       public String description;
       @SerializedName("cover")
       public Cover cover;
   }
   ```
2. Используя `Gson` парсим входной объект:

   ```
   Type listType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Example>>() {}.getType();
   List<Example> yourClassList = new Gson().fromJson(jsonArray, listType);
   ```

Answer (score 2):

То, что в фигурных скобках это `JsonObject`, то, что в квадратных `JsonArray`. В вашем примере, `JsonArray` это сам корень `json` и поле `genres`.

Посмотрите [примеры из документации](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/json-1973242.html), там все очень наглядно и понятно.

Comment: Т.е. json, имеющий такую структуру, как та, что я показал -- это и есть JSONArray, состоящий из JSONObject? А внутри каждого JSONObject имеется еще один JSONArray, так?

Comment: что-то вроде такого  :)